# How to fix Error "Module parse failed: Unexpected character" in laravel mix

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack, laravel-8, laravel-mix

I'm using laravel-mix in Laravel8 to write react code and compile then.

In normal use everything is right. but when I want to load an mp4 file into react using line below:

```js
 require(`./files/${mp4file}`)
```

I receive this error for loading `mp4` file during compile with laravel-mix by `npm run dev`:

```
ERROR in ./resources/files/5.mp4 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

**NOTE:** I have this program in `create-react-app` and it works very well without no problem during `build` and `run`.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After one day I found the solution,

You need to build your custom loader. For doing that I added this line to `webpack.mix.js`:

```js
mix.extend("addWebpackLoaders", (webpackConfig, loaderRules) => {
    loaderRules.forEach((loaderRule) => {
        webpackConfig.module.rules.push(loaderRule);
    });
});

mix.addWebpackLoaders([
    {
        test: /\.(mp4|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        use: [
            { 
                loader: 'file-loader',            
            }
          ]
    }
]);
```

By this way you've added `file-loader` for such files like `mp4`,`svg`,`gif`. After that you can run `npm run dev`.

This link helped me:
https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/145